# checking what the previous versions of a package that were installed or checking transaction records for apt

Tags: apt, software-installation

I've got an ubuntu system that was upgraded from 12.04 (I think) to 14.04. I have a bunch of packages that were held, which I had to finesse into working, and a lot of non held packages.

I did the whole shebang - apt-get dist-upgrade, aptitude for reluctant packages, and ended up with a fully updated systems

One of the non held packages (from what looks like an internal mirror of a PPA) is marked as for update, and I'd like to know when, and how the last 2-4 package updates for that happened, and better yet when.

Is there some mechanism in apt for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt` is just a front end for `dpkg`. transactions are recorded in dpkg.log you can get a list of recently installed packages with a terminal with the command `zcat -f /var/log/dpkg.log* | grep "\ install\ " | sort` which will give you a nicely sorted list with the most recent installation at the bottom or with the GUI by running the System Log application and choosing dpkg.log from the left menu as:

[image: dpkg.log.png]

Sources: Experience and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

Comment: heh, just worked it out a moment ago. Will select this as the correct answer as soon as the system allows me.